# Initializing the Angular Model using an Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngulasJS Demo3</title>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function nameController($scope){
            $scope.firstname = 'John';
            $scope.lastname = 'Smith';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller = "nameController">
First Name : <input type = "text" data-ng-model="firstname"></input> 
<br />
<br />
Last Name : <input type = "text" data-ng-model="lastname"></input> 
<br />
<br />
Hello {{ firstname }} {{lastname}}

</body>
</html>
```

Initialized the model with an global function where I have declare Scope object and using it I am passing the firstname and lastname to the view.

Output :

Here the firstname and lastname values are not getting reflected.

[image]

JSFiddle Link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tech_boy/mgoffxfd/)

Edit : I found this code [here](https://github.com/curran/screencasts/blob/gh-pages/introToAngular/examples/snapshots/snapshot10/index.html), and the [output](http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/examples/snapshots/snapshot10/).

Answer (score 0):

I would usually reference my app directly by declaring it as a variable in the `JavaScript`, and then referencing the name of the app in the declaration in the `html` tag. The following will work:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>AngulasJS Demo3</title>
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
        myapp.controller('nameController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.firstname = 'John';
            $scope.lastname = 'Smith';
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="nameController">
    First Name : <input type = "text" data-ng-model="firstname"></input> 
    Last Name : <input type = "text" data-ng-model="lastname"></input> 
    Hello {{ firstname }} {{lastname}}
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lambo477/ehLcb59c/)

Comment: I know about this way to follow, Can you point out what's going wrong in the code I shared? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

For an angular application to work, you need to define the module. Which you have not done.

define a app like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

then refrence this app in your html like this:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myapp">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a running fiddler for you code [running Code](https://jsfiddle.net/mgoffxfd/2/)

you need always to have a defind app for the angular to work and the controller should be part of that app.

```html
 <title>AngulasJS Demo3</title>
 <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  myApp.controller("nameController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.firstname = 'John';
   $scope.lastname = 'Smith';
   }]);
 </script>

<body ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller = "nameController">
First Name : <input type = "text" data-ng-model="firstname"/> 
<br />
<br />
Last Name : <input type = "text" data-ng-model="lastname"/>
<br />
<br />
Hello {{ firstname }} {{lastname}}

</body>
```